# Rails Tutorial ch. 10 Test 10.20 failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I have problem with test 10.20 in Rails Tutorial.
After using command:

> bundle exec rake test:mailers

I've received error:

```
Run options: --seed 6131

# Running:

F

Finished in 0.559132s, 1.7885 runs/s, 5.3655 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
UserMailerTest#test_account_activation [/home/adam/workspace/sample_app    /test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:11]:
Expected: ["noreply@example.com"]
Actual: nil

1 runs, 3 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I've thoroughly checked my code and can't find the impropriety but I'm obviously doing it wrong.

Here's my user_mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

user_mailer_test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

I've added this line to config/environments/test.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

Can I have some advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `:from` to this line

```
mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
```

like this

```
mail to: user.email, from: "noreply@example.com", subject: "Account activation"
```

Comment: It's worked, thanks. But I even used copy/paste code from railstutorial and I dont see **from: "noreply@example.com"** that part of code.

Comment: Maybe they forgot it, but see this line in your test          assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from, it will only pass if the value :from is equal to "noreply@example.com"].

Comment: I saw this line in application_mailer. It looks like that:                            'class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end'

Comment: Yes this is another way to add the :from parameter, but I never used it tbh

Answer (score 2):

All references to the User mailer should start with

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
```

This is due to recent changes in Rails 4.2. I missed a couple of references when I updated the tutorial last week, but these have now been corrected. Be sure you also include the Application mailer as shown in [Listing 10.8](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#code-generated_application_mailer). In fact, it's probably a good idea to remove the mailers and regenerate them from scratch to make sure your code conforms to the structure expected by Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Simply edit the **user_mailer.rb** file from this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
```

to this:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
```

The reason being is that the `default from:` address is in the **application_mailer.rb** file and *it* pulls from `ActionMailer::Base`