# Rails Tutorial (M. Hartl) - I am receiving two errors and I need assistance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am getting 2 errors in my Ruby on Rails application. I am trying to complete the sample application from the Rails Tutorial.

Here are my errors:

```
1) Error:
UserMailerTest#test_account_activation:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)    app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:3:in `account_activation'     test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'

2) Failure:
UserMailerTest#test_password_reset [/home/andy/Ruby_Projects/sam
ple_app/test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:21]: Expected: ["from@example.com"] Actual: ["noreply@example.com"]
```

And here is my code for both issues:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:andy)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end

  test "password_reset" do
    mail = UserMailer.password_reset
    assert_equal "Password reset", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

Here is the UserMailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation
    user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

I have been following the tutorial checking my code with what is in the tutorial, but still unable to find what I have done wrong. Please let me know if you need any more information. I will try and provide it.

Comment: You might find [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614943/rails-tutorial-ch-10-test-10-20-failure) helpful.

Comment: Some feedback on posting: In future, please ensure you format your code properly and add the _railstutorial.org_ tag. It would also be useful to tell us which chapter you are in, also there is no such file as `UserMailer.rb`. And what is the file name where the first piece of code lives?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will keep that in mind. I am on Chapter 10. It was suppose to be user_mailer.rb, I just miss typed it by mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define the argument for the `account_activation` method.  You need to add a `user` argument:

```
def account_activation(user)
  @user = user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
end
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, I have fixed the first issue but, I still am unable to fix the second error message.

Comment: If you want to override the default from address, add a from: 'from@example.com' to the mail line along with to: and subject:.